# Python: return the column index of first true and add to the end of the column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing all boolean values as the the picture show.
I want to find the column index of first True value in every row and add to a new column in the end.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFLGV.png)

(Such as in my example, i am looking to add new column [-1,-1,8,-1,-1] )
I have tried to iterate through the rows and columns but failed

Comment: Why not -1, 4, 8, -1, -1 as this would seem to correspond to your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking for help, instead of linking to an image of data, please provide the example data in code like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'col1': [False, False, False, False, False],
    'col2': [False, False, False, False, False],
    'col3': [False, False, False, False, False],
    'col4': [False, False, False, False, False],
    'col5': [False, True, False, False, False],
    'col6': [False, False, False, False, False],
    'col7': [False, False, False, False, False],
    'col8': [False, False, False, False, False],
    'col9': [False, False, True, False, False],
    'col10': [False, False, False, False, False],
    'col11': [False, False, False, False, False]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You are far more likely to get help (and avoid down votes on your question) with this format.

To actually answer your question: I think what you want is this:

```
def find_first_true_index(row):
    for i, value in enumerate(row):
        if value:
            return i
    return -1

df['first_true_index'] = df.apply(find_first_true_index, axis=1)
```

The output is:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | col10 | col11 | first_true_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | -1 |
| False | False | False | False | True | False | False | False | False | False | False | 4 |
| False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | 8 |
| False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | -1 |
| False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | -1 |

**However**, while my answer does provide the column index on the first true in every row, it does NOT match the [-1,-1,8,-1,-1] output you expected as there is a "TRUE" in the 5th column (index = 4) on row two in the example data.

Comment: Thank you so much,  i kept on interating over all the cells but running into type error.   I am still struggling with python's methdology of data manipulation since i have been coding C++ for years.  There are significant differences in understanding data, pointers, and others

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help. If you wouldn't help hitting accept if you're happy with the answer, that would be great. I'm trying to boost the old reputation :)

Comment: Just accepted.  Again, it helps a lot.